# How to remove duplicate item in Dart

Tags: dart

So here is how i set my data

```
  loadNotification(int limit, int offset) async {
    List<Notification> notif =
        await fetchNotification(http.Client(), limit, offset);
    tempNotification.addAll(notif);

    _notificationController.add(tempNotification);
  }
```

and here is my `Notification()`

```
class Notification {
  final String notificationId;
  final String notificationTitle;
  final String notificationBody;
  final String notificationDate;
  final String notificationTo;
  final String notificationImage;

  Notification({
    this.notificationId,
    this.notificationTitle,
    this.notificationBody,
    this.notificationDate,
    this.notificationTo,
    this.notificationImage,
  });

  factory Notification.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Notification(
        notificationId: json['notificationId'] as String,
        notificationTitle: json['notificationTitle'] as String,
        notificationBody: json['notificationBody'] as String,
        notificationDate: json['notificationDate'] as String,
        notificationTo: json['notificationTo'] as String,
        notificationImage: json['notificationImage'] as String);
  }
}
```

so for an example my first data will show 1,2,3,4,5 then i click load more it will show 1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7.

I already try to change my `loadNotification` to this

```
  loadNotification(int limit, int offset) async {
    List<Notification> notif =
        await fetchNotification(http.Client(), limit, offset);
    tempNotification.addAll(notif);
    filteredNotification = tempNotification.toSet().toList();
    _notificationController.add(filteredNotification);
  }
```

but still no help, how can i achieve it ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tempNotification.toSet().toList()
```

Does't work as you expect because you have to override equals and hashCode for  Notification class, only in this case you will compare by value otherwise by ref

Some example based on notificationId:

```
class Notification {
  final String notificationId;
  ...
  bool operator ==(o) => o is Notification && notificationId == o.notificationId;
  int get hashCode => notificationId.hashCode;
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement it ? i'm bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use a map, because a map only contains uniques. Like this:

```
Map<String, Notification> notificationsMap = {}

if(!notificationsMap.containsKey(notification.id)){
 notificationsMap[notification.id] = notification;
}

--

In your example:
// please write out the whole name, it gets confusion otherwise

List<Notification> notifications = await fetchNotification(http.Client(), limit, offset);

notifications.forEach((Notification notification){
  if(!notificationsMap.containsKey(notification.id)){
    notificationsMap[notification.id] = notification;
  }
});

-> now you can access all notifications by e.g. calling:

notificationsMap.keys.toList();
```